# how to calculate gamma function in programming language?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, gamma-function

how to calculate gamma function in programming language?
I also need to support complex numbers (complex numbers are in the programming language) and negative numbers. thank you :)

Comment: Any *particular* programming language you have in mind ... ?

Comment: C#, maybe C++.
complex is class in those.

Comment: not for complex!

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Lanczos approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation).

Comment: what is "$g$"?<br>
what is "$p_n$"?<br>
@rlgordonma

Comment: @Lior: $g$ can be any real number, but is selected for optimum accuracy with as few terms as possible.  In the Python code, they choose $g=7.0$.  The $p_n$ are the coefficients defined in the article and are precomputed in the Python code for $g=7.0$.

Comment: how to define $p_n(x)$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation#Coefficients